# Overriding column-width, or flexible column-width?

Tags: jquery, html, css, column-width

I know stuff that has to do with CSS columns aren't really well supported yet by browsers (column-breaks and whatnot), but is there any way, CSS/jQuery/whatever, that I could override column-width?

For example, let's say I have a column-width of 300px but I need one of the columns to be the width of an inserted image, be it larger or smaller than 300px?

I can't predict where users enter images, so the column-width really has to be applied to the entire content area, meaning it CAN'T be done in three DIVs or whatever, one of which is the image and each of which has their own specified width.

Been trying to figure this out for a few days now, I'm going bonkers over here. There must be SOME way! :)

**Fiddle here**: http://jsfiddle.net/wpzpzabf/2/
Note that the image is supposed to be around 1.5x of the column width (on Chrome and IE the rest of the image is hidden while on FF it overlaps the following column).

**Here's an example of the end result I'm after**:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159548794/img-columns.png]

```
.wrapper {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.inner {
    height:300px;

    -webkit-column-width:300px;
    -moz-column-width:300px;
    column-width:300px;
}
.inner img {
    display:block;
    max-height:300px;
}
```

Comment: Can adjust virtually any css using script. Please show your code as well as a demo would be helpful

Comment: Added Fiddle example.

Comment: Is this what you want? I just set max-width for image http://jsfiddle.net/wpzpzabf/3/

Comment: Negative. What I want is for the image to be the height of the column and make the column the image is in match the width of the image, whether it's longer or shorter than the text columns. Here's an example of what I'm after: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159548794/img-columns.png